# Create separate registered user groups in joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla1.5

I have a website and I want to create two separate registered user groups. Ex. Student and Teacher. Both are registered user groups.
I found only documentation to separate registered users from guests.

Comment: You cannot add any more group in Joomla 1.5. I would recommend you to upgrade your site to latest stable Joomla version.

Comment: To add onto what Toretto said - by upgrading you'll be able to create multiple groups.  If you MUST use 1.5 - there may be components/workarounds in place, but I am sure they come with inherent risks.